# AngularJS custom validation against a resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-resource

I have an angular form which performs custom validation of all fields, anytime any form field changes. The validity of each value can change, based on the value of other values in the form, hence the validation of the entire form with each edit.

The validation works correctly, but the form field being edited, loses focus every time the validation is performed (each key-press). I'm pretty sure this is down to a flaw in my validator implementation (which I copied off somewhere on the internet months ago and can no longer find).

The problem occurs in Chrome, but not in IE9.

Below is the implementation. Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong here, that would cause the focus problems I'm getting?

```
angular.module('myComponent').directive('myValidator', function (MyApiResource) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs, ctrl) {
            function myValidator(value) {
                if (value) {
                    var myObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(scope.myObject));
                    myObject[attrs.name] = value;
                    MyApiResource.validate(myObject, function (uiValidationFailures) {
                        for (var attributeName in myObject) {
                            if (scope.correctionForm[attributeName]) {
                                var valid = !uiValidationFailures.filter(function (el) { return el.AttributeName === attributeName; }).length;
                                scope.correctionForm[attributeName].$setValidity('myValidator', valid);
                                if (valid && attributeName !== attrs.name && scope.correctionForm[attributeName].$pristine) {
                                    scope.correctionForm[attributeName].$setViewValue(myObject[attributeName]);
                                }
                                scope.uiValidationFailures[attributeName] = valid
                                    ? undefined
                                    : uiValidationFailures.filter(function (el) { return el.AttributeName === attributeName; });
                            }
                        }
                        return value;
                    });
                    return value;
                }
                scope.uiValidationFailures[attrs.name] = undefined;
                return undefined;
            };
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(myValidator);
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(myValidator);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I cannot find anything wrong with your code there (without further context), there's an alarm bell going off when you say

> The problem occurs in Chrome, but not in IE9.

Plus you're talking about a form field losing focus. My guess is that there will probably be some inconsistencies - perhaps in the focus behavior? - between the two browsers. It is unlikely to be a JavaScript issue.